# Node voltage calculation

Tags: circuit-protection, undervoltage, nodal-analysis

I'm designing a protection circuit and I'm assuming the following hypothetical situation represented in the figure below, where I need to determine the value of Vx. Does anyone have any suggestions on what the value of Vx would be?

[image]

Comment: It looks like \$V_x\$ is directly connected to +5V on the left (labelled I/O) in which case it would also be +5V. It's not really clear what's on the left side of your circuit

Comment: @Hilmar on the left is a microcontroller, the 5V is the output voltage of the I/O pin

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to accomplish here. \$Vx\$ is not a value that can be set, it depends on the conditions you're operating at. GodJihyo's answer pretty much sums it up

Comment: Safe range for Vx can be read from the microcontroller data sheet. The safe range will also be different depending on if the pin is an input or an output.

Answer (score 2):

It would depend on the microcontroller output, how much current it can source and sink, if it's high, low or high impedance, how close to the supply rails it can go.
If the controller was able to go from 0V to 5V with zero output impedance Vx will be whatever the output is. If it's in a high impedance state the -15V will be clamped by D2 and Vx will be -0.3V. 
In the real world, Vx would depend on the actual voltage and impedance of the output, basically it's Thevenin equivalent.

Comment: Yes, @GodJihyo! It was just an idealized question. I'm assuming the 5V at the microcontroller output. I know that in practice there are voltage and current limitations. The doubt was that, in this situation, the resistor D2 will not act, so in practice the resistance must be high enough to limit the current that will be drained from the microcontroller, which will be approximately 20V/R.